# Alfresco - Get licence details inside a webscript

Tags: javascript, java, alfresco

I am currently developing a monitoring page for a client and they would like to include a field which shows the current status of the Alfresco license (currently active? days remaining? ...)

Would anyone have any experience with this or any tips?

I tried Googling to see if there was any service that could provide this info but sadly 'Alfresco', 'licence' and 'java' are very commonly used together ;-)

Comment: Grab the `LicenseService` / get it injected into your java bean, then call [getLicense()](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/service/license/LicenseService.html#getLicense--) on it?

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what i needed! Did not know about the LicenseService

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promoting a comment to an answer...

You need to write a java-backed webscript. Have the `licenseService` bean injected into it. The `licenseService` bean provides [LicenseService](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/service/license/LicenseService.html). From that, call [LicenseService.getLicense()](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/service/license/LicenseService.html#getLicense--), which returns a [LicenseDescriptor](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/service/license/LicenseDescriptor.html). On that you'll find everything you need for days left, license mode etc

Also, don't forget that you can call a built-in webscript to get the license details too! It's how Share works to display its info on the license. Call `/alfresco/service/api/admin/restrictions?guest=true` to get it